# Convert attribute/value pairs of a DOM element into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shortcut function that converts a DOM element and its various attribute/value pairs to a corresponding Javascript object?

E.g convert this in the HTML page:

```
<div id="snack" type="apple" color="red" size="large" quantity=3></div>
```

to an object in Javascript, as if you had typed:

```
var obj = {
        id:  "snack"
        type: "apple"
        color: "red"
        size: "large"
        quantity: 3
};
```

Comment: If there isn't this is a great idea for a plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really a shortcut but at least a short implementation that does what you want:

```
var attributes = document.getElementById('someId').attributes;
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0, len = attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
    obj[attributes[i].name] = attributes[i].value;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest: `(var i = 0, len = attributes.length; i < len; i++)`, otherwise the `attributes.length` will be re-evaluated on every iteration, which isn't a *huge* performance hit, but it's (probably) unnecessary unless you expect nodes to be removed/appended during the for loop.

Comment: Agreed and updated. Even AFAIK todays js engines caches the objects path after first hit and gain performance.

Answer (score 2):

In a more functional style, one statement:

`[].slice.call(attributes).reduce(function(obj,attr){obj[attr.name] = attr.value;return obj;},{})`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use HTML data and JQuery?

```
// First, append the attributes with `data-`. 
<div id="snack" data-type="apple" data-color="red" 
     data-size="large" data-quantity="3"></div> 


// Then use jQuery to retrive the data, for this case, 
// the `snack` variable is populated
var snack = $("#snack").data();

for(prop in snack) {
    alert(prop + " => " + snack[prop]);
}
```

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/q6t2a/)

I'm not sure if you're allowed to use jQuery

Comment: This is great!  Wish I could select two answers.  The first answered as I asked, and this re-articulates the question in a very useful way for the task at hand.

Comment: Instead of the alert, how can you add all the attribute pairs to a variable to be used on another element?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in 2021.

```
let attributes = document.getElementById('snacks').attributes
let obj = [...attributes].reduce((o,a)=>{ o[a.name] = a.value; return o},{})
```

Comment: Also, if you want to filter out certain attributes, such as the id, you can throw in a filter() in the middle.

`[...attributes].filter(a=>a.name!='id').reduce((o,a)=>{ o[a.name] = a.value; return o},{})`